# How to store the output of a python script in a variable

Tags: python

I have a python script 'script1.py' which creates a dictionary 'out_dict' at the end of the execution. I'm calling 'script1.py' from another script 'script2.py'.

Is there any way to get only the final dictionary 'out_dict' (note : I have some print statements too in 'scirpt1.py') into a variable in 'script2.py'.

script1.py

```
......
......
some print statement
......
some print statement
......
out_dict = {...}
print(out_dict)
```

script2.py

```
import os
val = os.system("python3.6 script1.py")
```

Comment: can you print the output?

Comment: You can insert something like `print("MARKER")` right before `print(out_dict)` and then split `val` on this marker string and use only the second field of the split. Given that both scripts are in Python, wouldn't it be easier/better to just import one into the other and then directly pass dictionaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the start of `script1.py` add

```py
import pickle as p
```

and after your dict was created add

```py
with open('dict.p', 'wb') ad f:
    p.dump(out_dict, f)
```

Then in `script2.py` again import pickle but this time load from a file

```py
import os
import pickle as p
val = os.system("python3.6 script1.py")

with open('dict.p', 'rb') as f:
    your_dict = p.load(f)     # your dict will loaded
```

OR

You can not save your dict into a file at all and just access it from `script1.py` like a class var, but you will have to import your first script though.

`script2.py` example:

```py
import script1

your_dict = script1.out_dict     # your dict var from the first script
print (out_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

Easier method would be to import one file in another and use that **dictionary**:

**func.py**

```
def function():
    out_file=dict()
    # Your Code
    return out_file
```

**main.py**

```
import func
val = func.function()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare 2 files. The first will contain the function you want to call. Like this:

**func.py**

```
def myFunc():
    return 2
```

In the script you want to call the function you have to do this:

**main_script.py**

```
import func

val = func.myFunc()
print(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of doing this:

1. Store the output dictionary in another file which is then read by script2.py
2. As Daniel suggested, use a marker. It would remove the burden of another file but you would need an appropriate marker.